# Comparing characters in C

Tags: c, function, character

I have a question about comparing a single char of a string in C inside a function.
The code looks like this:

```
int fq(char *s1){
int i;
for(i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++){
    if(s1[i]=="?"){
        printf("yes");
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Even if s1="???" it never prints out yes. I have managed to solve the problem but i am curious as to why it works one way but not the other.
This is the piece of code that works:

```
int fq(char *s1,char *s2){
int i;
char q[]="?";
for(i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++){
    if(s1[i]==q[0]){
        printf("yes");
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you post declaration of array `s1`?

Comment: This `for(i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++)` is terrible, because you are iterating through the whole string in each iteration, this `for (i = 0 ; s1[i] != '\0' ; ++i)` would be a lot better. Also, it would be sufficient to do `if (s1[i] == 'q')` instead of what you do, and the problem has to be where you initialize `s1`.

Comment: @iharob: Why would it be iterating through the whole string? `strlen()` returns the string size so technically his for loop will run for the size of his string length.

Comment: @Javia1492 That's the principle, yes. In practice, `strlen` also iterates over the string every time you call it, to find the `\0`. Unless the optimization level is high enough, AND you tell the compiler that the string can't change, by using `const`.

Comment: @MrLister I see what you're saying. In other words, every time the for loop condition is evaluated, it will recompute `strlen` of the string. Correct?

Comment: @Javia1492 That's right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the first sample compares addresses instead of characters.

There is no string type in c and the `==` operator when applied to an array or a pointer, compares the addresses instead of the contents.

Your function would be correctly written like this

```
int fq(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; s1[i] ; ++i)
    {
        if (s1[i] == 'q')
            printf("yes");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

you can compare `s1[i]` to `'q'`.

Comment: Im not sure what you're trying to say with this sentence "There is no string type in c and the == operator when applied to an array or a pointer, compares the addresses instead of the contents." `==` is a valid C operator. See [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm).

Comment: I don't think I said it's not a valid operator, it's just that some programmers with c++, python or any language with a **string** type are used to comparing strings with the `==` operator which is of course valid, in c you can't use that operator to compare strings.

Comment: Hmm. I havent programmed in C for a long time (and it was embedded C) so i wasnt sure why you said that, but thanks for clarifying. I did not know C did not contain string types.

Comment: To be pedantic, the phrase "compares addresses instead of characters" is not correct. You compare the value of the character `s1[1]` to the address of the string `"?"`.

Answer (score 4):

`"?"` Isn't a `char` but a string with just one `char`

`'?'` Is a char and should return true in `s1[i] == '?'`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(s1[i]=="?"){
```

is not the right syntax to check whether `s1[i]` is the character `'?'`. It needs to be:

```
if(s1[i] == '?'){
```

You might want to investigate how you can change your compiler settings so that you get warnings when such expressions exist in your code base.

Using the option `-Wall` with `gcc`, I get the following message:

```
cc -Wall    soc.c   -o soc
soc.c: In function ‘fq’:
soc.c:7:15: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
       if(s1[i]=="?"){
               ^
soc.c:7:15: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
```

Answer (score 0):

In C character array i.e. string has syntax as "". For a single character the syntax is ''.

In your case: it should be: `if(s1[i]=='?')`

If you want to compare it in string form you need to strcmp. Because the '==' operator is not capable to compare strings in C.

To compare two strings we can use: `if(!strcmp(s1,q))`

And for this operation you need to add string.h header like: `#include <string.h>`

To compare strings with '==' operator you need to overload the operator. But, C does not support operator overloading. To do so you can use C++ language.